# Can not start mysql server: Bind on unix socket: No such file or directory

Tags: mysql, mac

Recently I try to install mysql on my MacBookPro,but can't start server with logs:

```
[ERROR] Can't start server : Bind on unix socket: No such file or directory
[ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on socket: /tmp/mysql.sock ?
```

Any suggestions?Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check which process is already using this port (mysqld is using socket 3306 by default):

`netstat -lntp | grep 3306`

Stop or reconfigure that process and try to start mysql again.